# Why is FB not deduplicating my events? GTM

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager

I am using GTM web and server tracking for FB Conversion API. Everything seems to be setup correctly, but event manager is not deduplication my events for some reason. I am using event id for deduplication. As shown in the screenshot the event id for the ViewContent is the same, but still FB is not deduplicating. Any idea why is that? Thank you.[fb-events-manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTFE6.png)

I am using an event ID variable found in the GTM gallery by mbaersch

The same goes for other events, but the events manager in live debug is not showing the deduplication. This is what I see for the last 7 days [viewcontent deduplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmRsH.png)

Comment: We are using both event id and FBP. I guess event id's deduplication is weaker than FBP. Or can you make sure the event amount from web and server are the same.

Comment: @darrelltw Could you please assist me? How can I send FBP from browser GTM and server GTM in order to match in Events Manager? Thank you.

Comment: You might need to share some information. 1. How you send the request to server-side container. 2. How you choose the facebook CAPI template in server-side container. Please mask all the sensitive information

Comment: @darrelltw we are using ga4 to send the data to the server. On the server-side we are using Conversions API Tag from facebookincubator. We are using the same template for FB in the web container.
Here are some screenshot, hope it helps: https://imgur.com/a/UXMtHK9

Comment: hello @darrelltw. Thank you so much for the screenshots. That helped. It seems to working. However, the purchase event quality is still low, although Im sending customer information. But I cant see it in FB Events Manager. Im sending you a screenshot from the GA4 purchase event. Is this the way to send customer data to FB? Thank you so much for your help

https://imgur.com/a/SNDAIhp

Answer (score 0):

The template you use is `facebookincubator`

It can accept `fbp` and `fbc` though cookie or event parameter

```
// code from the template
event.user_data.fbp = eventModel['x-fb-ck-fbp'] || getCookieValues('_fbp', true)[0];
event.user_data.fbc = getFbcValue();
```

So when you sending event from client container to server container

We can add the parameter like

[image]

---

If you are not sure about how to get the cookie `fbp` `fbc`

[image]

---

To check if we are success to send the fbp information to facebook

Preview your server-side container

The request of the FB CAPI request should contain `fbp` like below

[image]